# Which has better XMPP integration: OTRS or RequestTracker?

Tags: debian, xmpp, otrs, rt

AFAIK, neither has native XMPP support, but maybe one or the other is easier to hack in that respect? I would need:
 - inform issue owner about ticket changes/updates
 - inform support conference room about new tickets
 - optional: allow creation of new tickets via Jabber
TIA!
(I like to use either OTRS 5.0 or RequestTracker 4.2 on Debian stable.)

Answer (score 0):

OTRS has a free plugin for Jabber (xmpp) integration [Jabber Notification](http://otrsaddons.com/content/jabbernotification)

Sadly it is produced for OTRS ver.3.x, but as much as I see it won't be difficult to update this for ver.5.x

Just take a look at how file /opt/otrs/Kernel/System/Ticket/Event/NotificationEvent/Transport/Email.pm is built. Copy it. And insert xmpp logics there

Answer (score 0):

All notifications in RT, including all of the native email notifications, are handled via scrips. To add XMPP notifications, you can add scrips, possibly mirroring the email notifications with On Create, On Correspond, etc. In the scrip action, use a Perl module to send the notifications you want. As part of the scrip condition and action, you can check for appropriate users in the reply (issue owner, AdminCcs like the support group, or Requestor on the ticket) and send the XMPP message to the right person or channel. The [Net::XMPP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::XMPP) module looks like it would be a good start.

Creating tickets via Jabber would be a little more work. I would create a daemon with the Net::XMPP client listening on the desired channel. You could then watch for a keyword and use the RT API to create a ticket when someone types "newticket: apply latest security patches". The Requestor could be the person who sent the message, and the subject and initial post to the ticket could be the message.